# Android Pay and Stripe - BasicNetwork.performRequest, Unmarshalling MaskedWallet

Tags: android, android-volley, stripe-payments, android-pay

For my mobile app, I am using Android Pay + Stripe as the payment gateway. I created a merchant account with Stripe and using the PUBLISHABLE key to generate a token. For the past week, obtaining the token to create a charge has been successful.

My Wallet Environment is the following:

```
public static final int WALLET_ENVIRONMENT = WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
```

However, today, I am seeing strange exceptions:

1)

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://sandbox.google.com/payments/apis-secure/instantbuy/android/v1/getFullWallet?
```

2)

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.wallet.MaskedWallet
10-28 11:50:02.638 906-1616/? E/Parcel: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.wallet.MaskedWallet
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.wallet.MaskedWallet" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

3)

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.wallet.shared.BuyFlowConfig
10-28 11:49:57.633 906-922/? E/Parcel: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.wallet.shared.BuyFlowConfig
```

4)

```
E/ServerConnection: Exception sending Volley request
10-28 10:55:01.868 20872-20927/? E/ServerConnection: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: com.google.android.gms.http.a: Blocked by rule: temporary_blocked2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has now been fixed. For some strange reason, I changed the WALLET_ENVIRONMENT to the following:

```
public static final int WALLET_ENVIRONMENT = WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST;
```

Then, I ran it once. Then, I rechanged it back to SANDBOX mode and it worked:

```
public static final int WALLET_ENVIRONMENT = WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
```